# Modern ActionBar without ActionBarActyivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The main activity of the application I'm working on, extends FragmentActivity. However, I'd like to use the `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` and `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.  Unfortunately, FragmentActivity does not have a setSupportActionBar() method.

So I can't use `FragmentActivity.setActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)`, and if I use an `android.widget.Toolbar` I can't pass that into the `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor

I'm trying to get the look of the action bar from newer applications, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

For reference, I'm trying to get the action bar to look similar to this.

[image]

I'm probably going about this completely wrong, so feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`. Please see Alex's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
```

Comment: I tried that, but a bunch of errors popped up in my main activity.  I'll try again later, and see if I can resolve the related errors.

Comment: Make sure you are importing everything from v7 packages as those duplicate  the native fragments packages

Comment: I switched to ActionBarActivity, and cleaned up all the errors.  Now the app starts, but the actionbar is blank (solid color). Do I need a layout file for the toolbar or something?

Comment: I think you can use getSupportActionBar().setTitle() and something like setIcon() or something. And your Activity menu goes to the ActionBar too, by itself.

Comment: Just read the documentation. Looks like the example I was going off, was missing quite a bit of important information. Thanks for your help.